# BeautifulSoup возвращает None, но элемент существует

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Элементы, которые находятся в начале страницы(без скролла) спокойно выдает, но оставшиеся элементы не видит. Причем код возвращает весь.

```
r = requests.get("https://www.oddsfan.com/prematch/events/120510871")       
t = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(t, 'lxml')
bl = soup.find('div', id='4-1_collapse')
print(bl)
bl1 = soup.find('div', id='4-11_collapse')
print(bl1)
```

Comment: На странице браузера? А те элементы в r.text нашлись?

Comment: @gil9red, r.text весь код выдает и элементы есть. первый элемент находит, второй none.

Comment: 1) Код возвращает весь, но при этом нет оставшихся элементов -- звучит странно 2) Я спрашивал насчет элементов в `text` потому что, раз часть элементов у вас нашлось, тогда куда делись остальные? Правильно -- javascript + ajax 3) `bl`, `bl1` у меня нашлись

Comment: @gil9red, а как сделать то тогда?

Comment: @gil9red, ajax запросы же отправляет, тогда код страницы должен был бы выдавать часть элементов, но он выдает все

Comment: Использовать, браузерные движки, которые смогут работать с js. Поищите, например "headless browsers". А так, я с подобным работал в Qt: QWebView (Qt4, WebKit) и QWebEngineView (Qt5, Chronium). Вы меня запутали. Тогда в чем вопрос? :)

Comment: @gil9red r.text показывает все элементы, если б был ajax показал бы только то что прогруженно. Но начинаю парсить и выдает элементы 4-1_collapse и 4-2_collapse. Причем выдает даже скрытый текст из этих блоков. А дальше не видит ничего, дак вот разве такое возможно что б выдавал в r.text весь код, но при парсинге видел только часть этого кода?